# modbus slave ID setting

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, library, modbus

I have small problem in setting device ID for Mosbus slave arduino. Here is simple example

In Modus library; device ID being configure hardcode while program. This code works for Me.

```
Modbus slave(1,0,0);
```

Now I wanted to recognise 0-255 device ID , I am using 8:1 digital Multiplexer & DIP switch to select the port. I am reading status of digital pin & depend on status of 8 DIP pin i come to know whats device ID. Below function return device ID. I have checked Serial it returns value properly. If i assign the value to Device ID it wont work . Please let me know how can i solve this.

```
unsigned int ID_Check() {
      unsigned   int ID_value;
      for(int row=0;row<8;row++)
      {
        digitalWrite(SO_enable,array[row][0]);
        digitalWrite(S1_enable,array[row][1]);
        digitalWrite(S2_enable,array[row][2]);
        Status_Out[row]=digitalRead(Output_Read);

      }

  ID_value = 1 * Status_Out[0] + 2 * Status_Out[1] + 4 * Status_Out[2] + 8 * Status_Out[3] + 16 * Status_Out[4] + 32 * Status_Out[5] + 64 * Status_Out[6] + 128 * Status_Out[7];
  return(ID_value);
}
```

Below is complete code.I tried to call function loop But it wont work

```
#include <ModbusRtu.h>
int SO_enable=5;
int S1_enable=4;
int S2_enable=3;
int Status_Out[8];
int Output_Read=2;
Modbus slave(ID_Check(),0,0); // this is slave @1 and RS-232 or USB-FTDI
int array[8][3]={
  {    
    0,0,0    }
  ,
  {    
    0,0,1    }
  ,
  {    
    0,1,0    }
  ,  
  {    
    0,1,1    }
  ,
  {    
    1,0,0    }
  ,
  {    
    1,0,1    }
  ,
  {    
    1,1,0    }
  ,
  {    
    1,1,1    }


};

unsigned int ID_Check() {
  unsigned   int ID_value;
  for(int row=0;row<8;row++)
  {
    digitalWrite(SO_enable,array[row][0]);
    digitalWrite(S1_enable,array[row][1]);
    digitalWrite(S2_enable,array[row][2]);
    Status_Out[row]=digitalRead(Output_Read);

  }

  ID_value = 1 * Status_Out[0] + 2 * Status_Out[1] + 4 * Status_Out[2] + 8 * Status_Out[3] + 16 * Status_Out[4] + 32 * Status_Out[5] + 64 * Status_Out[6] + 128 * Status_Out[7];
  return(ID_value);
}


uint16_t au16data[16] = 
{
  3, 1415, 9265, 4, 2, 7182, 28182, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1
};



void setup() {
  slave.begin( 9600 ); // baud-rate at 19200
  pinMode(SO_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 7 of arduino
  pinMode(S1_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 6 of arduino
  pinMode(S2_enable, OUTPUT) ;// pin can enable/disable using digital IO 5 of arduino
  pinMode(Output_Read,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  slave.poll( au16data, 16 );
}
```

The other way i tried

```
void Modbus_Setup()
{
  Device_ID=ID_Check();
     delay(100);
    Modbus slave(Device_ID, 0, 0); 
     slave.begin(9600);
  //slave.setID(Device_ID);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem may be initialisation order. In C/C++, global variables/objects are usually initialised in the order they are declared, and before any global functions run.

In your case, this means `ID_Check()` gets called before `array` is populated, and before `setup()` runs.

It looks like you need to make sure everything else is setup before your attempting to initialise the `Modbus` object. I'm not familiar with the library, but perhaps there's a way to set the device ID after it's been constructed (i.e. not in the constructor)?

If not, you could declare `slave` as a global pointer, and then instantiate it using `new` in `setup()`.

As a side note, I'm guessing your `Modbus_Setup()` function didn't work because the `slave` object in there is completely separate from the `slave` object that's declared globally and used in `loop()`.

Comment: can you show how can do it. How can declare slave as global pointer. As given in example ; if declare slave as globally & assign the device ID with No. code work. But my intension is to device id being update hw read

Comment: If i cant configure using mux & DIP switch . I need to configure manually. or i need to remember each device ID being used so to avois conflict.

Comment: I have tested their example code. When i declare slave globally. it will work. If i declare inside setup & assign slave ID . It wont work. How can assign my slave ID here.

Comment: @AMPS Declare it globally as `Modbus *slave = 0`. In `setup()`, instantiate it using `slave = new Modbus(...)`. (That's standard C++. I'd recommend looking up a tutorial on pointers if you're not familiar with them.)